# Phonegap for iOS is crashing

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am getting this message:

```
-[UIViewAnimationState release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1701d3740
```

It seems to be random - crashes like 6 times out of 10.

I am not sure I understand the message. How do I debug it?

[image]